# How do you solve a nonlinear first order ode (analytically or numerically), that itself does not have a reference to the independent variable

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, nonlinear-system

I am creating a dynamics question where an asteroid in space does not have enough tangential velocity to escape the pull of a planet, so it gradually will spiral around the planet eventually crashing into it. Now the question would ask the student to just find the position of the asteroid at a specific time $t = t_f\ \rm{s}$ where $t_f$ would be randomized such as the asteroid would not have crashed into the planet yet.

I started my derivation from Newton's Gravitational Law and the kinematics equation $v_r.dv_r=a_r.dr$, such as:

$${v_r.dv_r=\frac{-G.M}{r^2}.dr}$$
$$\int_0^{v_r}{v_r}.dv_r=-\int_{r_0}^r{\frac{G.M}{r^2}}$$
$$v_r^2=2.G.M.(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r_0})$$

Now, this is a non-linear first-order ode that I have tried everything I know to solve but failed miserably. MATLAB ODE solvers do not like this formulation as it does not contain the independent variable in the formulation. What ends up happening is it plugs the initial condition $r(0) = r_0 \rm \ m$, which gives back a velocity of $0\ \rm m/s$, which in turn would keep $r$ at $r_0$ repeating the cycle. I was wondering if there is some sort of solution, whether numerical or analytical to solve this kind of problem.

I am going to include the very basic code I wrote when trying to solve this problem.

```
R = 3*10^6;
d0 = 42000;
G= 6.6743*10^-11;
tspan= [0,1000];
r0= R+d0;
[t,r] = ode113(@(t,r) -(2*G*M*((1/r)-(1/(R+d0))))^0.5, tspan, r0);
plot(t,r);
```

[Plot for running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0hHx.png)

Comment: Gravity does not produce spiral orbits.

Comment: What you are simulating is the free fall directly and straight to the center of gravity. Any deviation from that would result in a term containing the angular momentum from $\dot\phi=L/r^2$. // For any other orbit the movement of the small body is symmetric to the periapsis, so if it comes from infinity it leaves to infinity. // The transformation to the energy equation requires the multiplication with $\dot r$, so will also have spurious solutions with $\dot r=0$ for purely formal reasons. To avoid them, start with $\dot r(0)\ne 0$, for instance by setting $r_0$ a little smaller than $R+d_0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I know that in reality, it is extremely difficult to create the situation I described. The question is a project question for a first-year dynamics course that requires the students to utilize the fundamental kinematics equation $v_r.dv_r=a_r.dr$. It is not a question about orbits. The problem I am encountering is with the ode it creates. The question can be replaced with the electromagnetic force between two charges ( with a neglection of magnetic forces and fixing one of the charges), but you would still arrive at an ode of the same form just different constants.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I tried exactly what you proposed either having my initial $r_0$ slightly smaller than my $R + d_0$ or having an initial velocity in the radial direction, but each is creating its own problems. Having that smaller $r_0$ is causing MATLAB to return imaginary numbers, and if there is an initial velocity in the radial direction the function would square the value removing the direction, which does not make sense as an outward radial direction should have a different path than an inward one. Why is there no way for the ode to be solved in its present form?

Comment: Getting imaginary numbers means it works. $r$ is hitting zero in finite time, you would have to define an event that terminates the integration when $r$ becomes negative (or if it reaches the surface). The direction of the velocity is determined by the sign before the square root, so here you get always a velocity towards the origin.